# jScrollPane плохо скроллит. Как сделать скролл более плавным и мягким?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Есть сайт
На нем в мобильной версии есть меню destination, по клику на которое самое меню и открывается.
Для сколла используется ScrollPane
Однако при скролле видно, что контент дергается и прокручивается рывками. Кто сталкивался с таким? Как сделать скролл более плавным и гладким?

UPD: Задача решена - проблема была в плагине unvelir

Comment: Что то с кэшированием + скрипты слишком часто меняют css во время прокрутки. Это можно увидеть в консольке разработчика в chrome включив мобильную версию сайта.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, да владелец сайта биткоины фармит ;)

Comment: @Visman Мода на покупку видеокарт кончилась, теперь чужие пользуют?

Comment: https://rere.vision/wp-content/themes/nenashev/js/readmore.min.js?ver=4.8.1 11 строка сильно грузит процессор.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич 11 строка это сам весь плагин. Там минифицированный файл

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас ошибка в Вашем коде или плагине, при скроле cpu нагружается на 100%, поэтому и возникает проблема, не видя код трудно что-то сказать. Попробуйте плагин обновить или другой использовать.

Comment: Там что то с кэшем. Я заметил, что спустя какое то время дергание прекращается, и загрузка CPU тоже.

Comment: спасибо. еще бы понимать куда копать и что делать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить атрибут в body, отключающий мерцание div без объявленных CSS.
Одному человеку помогло:

```
$("body").append('<h1 style="visibility:hidden">M</h1>');
```

[Источник:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089291/jquery-jerking-animation-only-happens-in-specific-circumstances)